# jquery hide child items in nested list

Tags: jquery, css

Im using this jquery code trying to expand a nested list. The code is almost working, when i click on the parent the nested list closes, when i click again it opens. The problem is when the page loads i want the child list to be closed not opened.  So i want the starting point of the nested list to be closed not opened.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('li.parent').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any guides or code i could add?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML also?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you simply hide the child elements, by chaining the `.children()` and `.hide()` methods, when you run the initial jQuery:

```
jQuery('li.parent').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).children('ul').toggle();
    return false;
}).children().hide();
```

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it's hard to give you an exact answer.  But you can either reference the elements in CSS and use `display:none;`

EXAMPLE:

```
li.parent>ul{
    display:none;
}
```

or something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('li.parent>ul').hide();
    jQuery('li.parent').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').toggle();
        return false;
     });
});
```